# Revolution Slider conflicting with Robly email form code

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, email

I am working on a website that needs a Robly email form inserted into the footer the problem is when I added the footer the revolution slider disappears. I believe it is this code that is creating a conflict because when I removed it the slider came back but the form would not submit the information.:

(script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"(/script)

I have tried inserting the code into the theme's footer.php usiing a child theme and also used a widget.

Comment: Have you got an example of the code?
From the sounds of things your might have 2 jquery libraries that are in conflict with each other. We are around Jquery 3 at the moment so you might have to upgrade your jquery version and slider/email to both play ball with the same version

Comment: I have the code for the Robly email form and the Revolution Slider is a plugin on WordPress.

Comment: Hi could you put the code/an example together and add it to your question?